# is OAuth required in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a problem .. i want to get all the feeds from a facebook page using fb graph API without OAuth but i have a problem

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page ID]/feed
i get the following response 

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}
```

while i check another page it gets right response

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[another page ID]/feed

{
   "data": [
      {
...
```

why it's asking for an access token for a page ... and it doesn't do that for another page ?

**EDIT**

i checked the first page Graph call 2 days ago and it was working 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be including an OAuth access token (whether it's a user's, if you're working directly on behalf of a user, or your app's, if you're not doing something in a user's context). Otherwise you might not be able to access all of the things that you should be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether or not you need OAuth but here is how you can **[get the access token](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)**.

**More Resources:**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OAuth is the only supported form of authentication.  However, some pages don't require it, such as fan pages (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed)

**EDIT**: Facebook has apparently changed their policy on this endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... so how can i make the fan page accept graph API calls without authentication ?

Comment: Also .... i have tested that fan page 2 days ago and it was working .. but now .. it doesn't

Comment: @From, it works for me using just `curl https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed`.

Comment: the coca cola works 100% ... but for my page .. i tested using regular graph API call and it was working ... but today it's not .. what do you think the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you control the page try the privacy options at http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12818

Comment: thanks a lot for your help .. but i edit the privacy it will return empty data object not an exception :(

Comment: It doesn't work for me from my Chrome browser, whether I am logged into Facebook or not. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716881/why-do-i-need-authentication-when-all-i-want-is-public-facebook-data/3716998