# View Facebook user's posts and shares without login

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Is it possible to see a Facebook user's posts and shares without login by using their Facebook public profile URL (like twitter) ?
If possible, how it is possible?

Comment: Are you writing an app for facebook? Normally they ask for permission.

Comment: Ya... i am working on IOS app.. I wanted to read the Post of a person by using their facebook public url (like twitter)... In twitter We can directly access the tweets of a person by using their public twitter url without login to the twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Facebook permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) will assist you in learning exactly what actions need specific permissions.
Instead of asking what *can* I get.  Ask yourself :

> Does the information I want require a certain permission?

If the answer to that question is "yes" ( and it usually will be ) then you will have to [authenticate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) the user and request the permission that you need before requesting that information.
With regard to your question :
You will need the `read_stream` permission to have access to the users news feed.  That is where all their posts are. Taken from the permissions link above :

> **read_stream**` :
> Provides access to all the posts in the user's News Feed and enables your application to perform searches against the user's News Feed

---

A previous answer to a question by [@berecursive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405906/berecursive) on this site explained why there is a difference between "public" data when you are using Facebook as a user and "public" data when an application is accessing the Graph API :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716998/558021

> ...Facebook does not mind you as a user seeing this information but does
>   not want applications to be able to harvest data. Obviously it would
>   be a lot faster for you to use the graph api to get everyone's names
>   off their posts to the group wall (hypothetical) than for you to do it
>   manually. The only publicly available information without an
>   access_token is the basic user information (and this is only for users
>   and not any other object)...